# Understanding this definition of a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I came across the following definition :
[image: Definition: Basis for a Vector Space]

I know that a basis for a vector space $V$ is a set of linearly independent vectors in $V$ that generates $V$.
The way I make sense of the given definition is this :

Each vector $v∈V$ can be expressed as a finite linear combination of $e_i$'s is just saying that {$e_1,e_2,...,e_n$} spans $V$. 
The uniqueness of the expressions ensures that all the vectors in the set $B$ are linearly independent. For, if they were linearly dependent, one of them could be expressed as a linear combination of the rest. Then we could just replace it with the aforementioned linear combination in any expression of a vector $v$ and in doing so, end up with multiple representations of $v$.

Is this somewhat correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me. You've understood how uniqueness fails with a linearly dependant set of vectors. I think of a basis $B$ as a minimal spanning set which is to say that it spans the vector space $V$ and any proper subset of $B$ fails to span $V$.